# using a vector in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to simulate a simple Register and the shift functionality. here the code I use :

```
entity shift is port (
CLK : in bit );
end shift ; 

architecture BEHAV of shift is 
signal  REG: bit_vector(9 downto 0) ;
signal  WORD: bit:='1'; 
begin
SYS :process (CLK)
begin 
    if CLK'event and CLK='1' then
    REG <= REG(9 downto 0) & WORD;  -- line cause the error
    end if;
end process SYS;
end BEHAV ;
```

I use a do file where I simulate the clock, but I get an error , that says :

```
# ** Fatal: (vsim-3420) Array lengths do not match. Left is 10 (9 downto 0). Right is 11 (0 to 10).
```

and idea what I'm doing wrong here ? 
thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of `REG` is 10 bits (`9 downto 0`), and into this you are trying to put `REG(9 downto 0) & WORD`. The total size of this expression is 10 + 1 = 11 bits. This doesn't fit into `REG`, which is itself 10 bits long.

You probably want `REG <= REG(8 downto 0) & WORD;`